# Error in Angular 8 reactive form file upload

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload file in Angular 8 but getting below error and not able to figure it out

```
ERROR DOMException: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
```

above error comes when I select a file. Below is my approach

Component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray,FormBuilder,FormGroup,FormControl, Validators, NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import { ApiService } from '../apis/commonapis';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  userForm : FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb : FormBuilder,private service : ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newForm(); 
  }
  newForm = function(){
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      email : ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      photo : ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    })
  }
  PostData(form: NgForm) {
    //console.log(form);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', this.userForm.get('photo').value);
    console.log(formData);
    /*this.service.PostApi("http://localhost:1900/addUser",formData).subscribe(res=>{
                console.log(res);
                location.reload();
            });
     */
  }

  onFileSelect(event) { // here is some error
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.userForm.get('photo').setValue(file);
    }
  }
}
```

template file

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="PostData(userForm)" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text"  formControlName='email' class="form-control" required>
                </div>                                                                                                    
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Photo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="file"  formControlName='photo' class="form-control" required  (change)="onFileSelect($event)">
                </div>                                                                                                    
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit"  value='submit' class="form-control">
                </div>                                                                                                    
        </div>

</form>
```

I have searched for above error and it says this error comes when DOM is not loaded but here element is already loaded than why this error?

Comment: With an admittedly superficial read of your code, all seems good.  I would suggest you create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) showing the error so that the members of SO can help you dig further.

Comment: @dmcgrandle  

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmfh1t

Comment: @user1234 refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291422/how-to-receive-file-upload-from-angular-reactive-form/55293543#55293543

Comment: @UshmiDave thanks a lot for paying attention to my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

That error is strange.
When I tested your code I received the following error:

> Error: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Just delete `formControlName='photo'` in your HTML template and should work.

EDIT

For displaying errors, you have to use a different approach than for regular inputs. File input doesn't have ng-touched, ng-untouched or ng-dirty classes, so you can't do something like:

```html
<p *ngIf="photo.invalid && (photo.dirty || photo.touched)"> Show an error </p>
```

I suppose you want to display the error for the file input when the user hits the submit button.
If so, you can do something like:

```js
// add a property to your class
isPhotoError = false;

PostData(form: NgForm) {
    if (this.userForm.get('photo').invalid) {
      this.isPhotoError = true;
    }
    //do something
 }

photoErrorHandler() {
    if (this.userForm.get('photo').hasError('required')) {
      return 'Photo required';
    }
  }
```

```html
<p *ngIf="isPhotoError"> {{ photoErrorHandler() }} </p>
```

Consider replacing your `onFileSelect(event)` with:

```js
onFileSelect(event: Event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.userForm.patchValue({ photo: file });
    this.userForm.get('photo').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

patchValue -> allows you to target a single control;

updateValueAndValidity() -> informs Angular that the value has been changed and it has to check if the value is valid or not.

I have created this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msz6q6) to check the code (sorry about the styles). I have included an image preview if you need one in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if i remove formControlName='photo'. Than how can i show errors related to this field.

Answer (score 1):

I came to a similar problem. Just like [Passionate Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5817313/passionate-coder) mentioned in the comment, the solution was to remove `formControlName` from `<input>`. It seems to me that the problem arises from the fact that we are initializing the `FormControl` with an empty string and then we are trying to enter the `File` type object, maybe that some inner type validation is throwing the occurring exception. In my opinion, the best option is to skip the `formControlName` directive usage and write some custom validation.

Change this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" formControlName='email' class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```